# Attached multiple file jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to upload more than one images, I have included `multiple` in the input area.
When upload second images, the first attached is removed.

```
<input name="images_post[]" id="files_post" size="27" type="file" multiple />
```

.

```
<input name="typeattach" type="hidden" id="typeattach" value="0"></span>
```

jQ

```
            $('#files_post').click(function() {                     
                $('#typeattach').val('1');
                $('#atach-value').val('');
            });

            $(':file').change(function () {
                $('#num-files').text(this.files.length);
            });
```

html

```
<span id="num-files">0</span>
```

When first files is attached, I attached second files.. the first file suddenly missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an `input` accept multiple files, the form must be `multipart/form-data` for its encoding type. Then you may select multiple files.

```
<!-- IMPORTANT:  FORM's enctype must be "multipart/form-data" -->
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>

<ul id="fileList"></ul>
```

Here's a script to test out handling those multiple files:

```
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
var list = document.getElementById('fileList');

// Clears the file list if it currently has child nodes.
while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
    list.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
}

// For each file...
for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
    // ...Add it to the ul as a li element.
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.innerHTML = 'File ' + (x + 1) + ':  ' + input.files[x].name;
    list.append(li);
}
```

**Just for completeness, even if the answer's accepted already...**

If you're trying to make it so that the file selection prompt can be opened multiple times, then multiple files can be chosen, then you have to be a little hacky. I believe (do not quote me, however) you cannot select files from multiple file prompts because of security. If you want to maintain the list of files for upload after the first prompt, then we must:

- Hide the current selected files by hiding the `input` with the selection once the selection of files has been made,
- Recreate the current `input` for consecutive uploads,
- Show the cumulative list of files in some other way,
- Upload all hidden inputs once the form is submitted.

Something like:

```
// Handles immediately after a file is selected
$("input#files_post").change(function () {
    var inputClone = this.clone();

    // Add to (hidden) list.
    inputClone.appendTo("#file-catalog");

    // Reset element
    this.remove();
    inputClone.appendTo("#file-upload-form");
});

// Handles what is uploaded on form submission
$("file-upload-form").submit({
    // Get only the file-catalog elements, serialise for upload.
    var fileParams = $("#file-catalog").find("*:form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dot.com/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success! Info: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

for the HTML:

```
<form id="file-upload-form">
    <input name="images_post[]" id="files_post" size="27" type="file" multiple />
    <div id="file-catalog" display="none"></div>
</div>
```

And utilise the original answer's JS, with a few editions I'll leave to you, if you wish to list the hidden files. Perhaps having a clear all button would be good for that list, too:

```
$(".clear-button").click(function() {
    $("#the-list-you-made-on-the-advice-above").empty();
    $("#file-catalog").empty();
}
```

Comment: I did this in my form, enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: When first files is attached, i try to attached second files, the first file is missing.

Comment: How exactly are you doing this? Selecting one file then clicking OK on the file prompt? To select multiple files you will have to follow the commands given to you by your operating system, as that's where the prompt comes from. It's part of your OS's file management software. So, if you're on Windows, to select multiple files you must click whilst holding the CTRL key, as you do in Windows File Explorer when you open a folder on your computer.

Comment: To clarify, the first file isn't "missing" after selection. You are selecting the files in the prompt, selecting that you've chosen the files you wanted, and you're then clicking it again and selecting a new bunch of files, effectively resetting and repeating the file selection operation. So obviously the computer clears up your previous selection. This is to be expected. Hold down CTRL and click the files you want, continuing to hold CTRL for as long as you wish to click more files. Then press OK on the prompt.

Comment: @mark1970 check the edit, as I believe that that might be what you want to do. It's convoluted to do, but it should work!